# фильтр слайдер по атрибутам woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Можно ли это както реализовать? слайдер понятное дело можно. Но под слайдером еще есть два инпута, куда человек вводит максимальное и минимальное значения. Понятное дело что в атрибутах я не могу ввести значения от 0 до 100000 по одной цифре, чтоб типо работал как стандартный слайдер на цену в вукоммерсе. Получается введённое значение в инпуте, нужно как-то округлять до существующего значения которое есть в атрибутах... если ктото понял о чем я.. то можно ли както это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если что - на скринах не слайдер, а фильтр.

Comment: под словом слайдер я имею ввиду ползунок

Comment: Не надо "иметь ввиду". Надо правильно употреблять термины. Слайдер - это совершенно другое.